# How to stick lamp holder to cable?

Tags: electrical, wire, bulb

I recently bought some bulb holders and now I'm wondering how I am supposed to attach them to the wire. I don't want the whole lamp to hang only on the small, exposed power connections inside. In the picture below you can see a black plastic nut holding the cable to the bulb holder. It didn't come with the holder, and I assumed they're easy to find, but now I have no idea what to search for. Is there a name for these parts?

[image: seller product photo]

Comment: It’s called a strain relief or cord grip but that’s not a good search term generally because too much will be returned.  I used Amazon search to find [these](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01E6U2ITU/ref=cm_sw_r_sms_c_api_7uZsBbRG9PR33) by looking up the metal shell sockets and then looking at related items.

Comment: @Tyson thank you so much! I was able to immediately find what I was looking for using your search terms.